# how to select reservations of today in sql for wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, date, getdate

What am I doing wrong here?
I'm trying to select reservations of today but it results in nothing.

```
SET @date = 'GETDATE(YYYY-MM-DD)';
SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`
WHERE (CONVERT(`meta_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%"@date"%');
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your code doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You want to evaluate the `@date` variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You could try this if you are using MYSQL database**

SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`
WHERE `database`.`table`.`Date_Column` =  CURRENT_DATE;

Or

**For SQL Server you could do this**

SELECT * FROM `database`.`table`
WHERE `database`.`table`.`Date_Column` =  CONVERT(date, GETDATE());

Hope this would help you!

Comment: What's '==' in MySQL?

Comment: this worked for me thank you (SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `database`.`table`.`Date_Column` = CURRENT_DATE;)

Comment: '==' is a comparison operator